# How to load .glb models in a-frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

I am trying to load `.glb` models in a-frame using the `gltf-model` component but I get the following error;

`components:gltf-model:warn Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0`

Based on the docs [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html) and the discussion [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2420) I believe I am doing this correctly. Please see my code below.

```
  <a-scene>
      <a-assets>

        <a-asset-item 
          id="glbtestmodel"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.com/90a30469-f038-4054-be9c-fd1ec94a810d%2Fkitchentest.glb?1537178470645">
        </a-asset-item>

      </a-assets>

      <a-entity 
          id="glbtest"
          gltf-model="#glbtestmodel"
          position="0 1 -2">
      </a-entity>

    </a-scene>
```

Using a-frame `8.2`

```
https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js
```

And you can see a glitch of that [here](https://quaint-nickel.glitch.me/).

I use [Vectary](https://www.vectary.com/) to export models, and `gltf` models exported from there always work using the same technique as expected.

As an alternative to exporting `.glb` from vectary, I have tried exporting the models as `gltf` and then converting them using suggested tools like [this](https://sbtron.github.io/makeglb/) and [this](https://glb-packer.glitch.me/). The result is the same.

Every model that I export in whatever fashion, I check using [this gltf-viewer tool](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and there are no errors. I have opened up the file and they are in `2.0` format as they should be.

In response to the error, I have also tried opening up the `.glb` file and modifying it removing the initial characters so that it matches the beginning of a `gltf` file but it just produces different errors.

Is this a known issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

The model in question is available via the above code example but [here is a direct link](https://cdn.glitch.com/90a30469-f038-4054-be9c-fd1ec94a810d%2Fkitchentest.glb?1537178470645) for ease.

If you need any more information from me to help advise, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `https://cdn.glitch.com/90a30469-f038-4054-be9c-fd1ec94a810d%2Fkitchentest.glb` instead of `https://cdn.glitch.com/90a30469-f038-4054-be9c-fd1ec94a810d%2Fkitchentest.glb?1537178470645`. The loader uses the file extension to determine if the file is JSON (gltf) or binary (glb). The number confuses the parser and goes through the JSON path, that's why you get the `components:gltf-model:warn Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0` message

Comment: Aha! That works perfectly, thank you very much. I didn't realise I could take number off the URL. Thanks again.